# Implementation of Plotly on pandas dataframe from pyspark transformation

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-science

I'd like to produce plotly plots using pandas dataframes. I am struggling on this topic.

Now, I have this:

```
           AGE_GROUP                       shop_id         count_of_member
0                 10                             1                      40
1                 10                            12                   57615
2                 20                             1                     186
4                 30                             1                     175
5                 30                            12                  322458
6                 40                             1                     171
7                 40                            12                  313758
8                 50                             1                     158
10                60                             1                     168
```

Some shop might not have a record. As an example, plotly will need `x=[1,2,3]`, `y=[4,5,6]`. If my input is `x=[1,2,3]` and `y=[4,5]`, then x and y is not the same size and an exception will be raised. I need to add a null value record for the missing shop_id. So, I need this:

```
           AGE_GROUP                       shop_id         count_of_member
0                 10                             1                      40
1                 10                            12                   57615
2                 20                             1                     186
3                 20                            12                       0
4                 30                             1                     175
5                 30                            12                  322458
6                 40                             1                     171
7                 40                            12                  313758
8                 50                             1                     158
9                 50                            12                       0
10                60                             1                     168
11                60                            12                       0
```

For each age_group, I need to have 2 shop_id since the unique set of shop_id is 1 and 12
if there are 10 age_group, 20 rows will be shown.
For example:

```
           AGE_GROUP                       shop_id         count_of_member
1                 10                            12                   57615
2                 20                             1                     186
3                 30                             1                     175
4                 40                             1                     171
5                 40                            12                  313758
6                 50                             1                     158
7                 60                             1                     168
```

there are 2 unique shop_id: 1 and 12 and 6 different age_group: 10,20,30,40,50,60
in age_group 10: only shop_id 12 is exists but no shop_id 1. 
So, I need to have a new record to show the count_of_member of age_group 10 of shop_id 1 is 0.
The finally dataframe i will get should be:

```
           AGE_GROUP                       shop_id         count_of_member
1                 10                            12                   57615
**1                 10                             1                       0**
2                 20                             1                     186
**2                 20                            12                       0**
3                 30                             1                     175
**3                 30                            12                       0**
4                 40                             1                     171
5                 40                            12                  313758
6                 50                             1                     158
**6                 50                            12                       0**
7                 60                            12                       0
7                 60                             1                     168
```

`** are the new added rows`

How can i implement this transformation?

Comment: _Plotly doesn’t allow me to do so_ Do what? It isn’t clear what your question is, can you explain things further?

Comment: Plotly doesn't allow me to have a different size of array input.
for example: x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6]
if x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5], then x and y is not the same size, exception throw

Comment: Any further explanations should be added to your post, not comments. _exception throw_ What exception? _how can i implement this transformation?_ I thought this question was about Plotly?

Comment: The question is about how to add those null value rows.

Comment: Can you explain/describe the algorithm for adding those?

Comment: i add new explanation in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i implement this transformation?

First of all, ***you don't have to***.
When used correctly, plotly has got a wide array of approaches where you can visualize your dataset as it is when your data look like yours in the third sample:

```
           AGE_GROUP                       shop_id         count_of_member
1                 10                            12                   57615
2                 20                             1                     186
3                 30                             1                     175
4                 40                             1                     171
5                 40                            12                  313758
6                 50                             1                     158
7                 60                             1                     168
```

There's no need to apply pandas to get to the structure of the fourth sample. You're not to clear on what you'd like to do with this sample, but I suspect you'd like to show the accumulated `count_of_member` per `age group` split by `shop_id` like this?

[image]

You may wonder why the blue bars for `shop_id1` isn't showing. But that's just because the size of the numbers are so hugely different. If you replace the miniscule `count_of_member` for `shop_id=1` to something more comparable for those of `shop_id=12`, you'll get this instead:

[image]

Below is a complete code snippet where the altered dataset has been commented out. The dataset used is still the same as in your third data sample.

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = {'AGE_GROUP': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 30, 5: 30, 6: 40, 7: 40, 8: 50, 10: 60},
                     'shop_id': {0: 1, 1: 12, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 12, 6: 1, 7: 12, 8: 1, 10: 1},
                     'count_of_member': {0: 40,
                      1: 57615,
                      2: 186,
                      4: 175,
                      5: 322458,
                      6: 171,
                      7: 313758,
                      8: 158,
                      10: 168}}

## Optional dataset
# data = {'AGE_GROUP': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 30, 5: 30, 6: 40, 7: 40, 8: 50, 10: 60},
#                      'shop_id': {0: 1, 1: 12, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 12, 6: 1, 7: 12, 8: 1, 10: 1},
#                      'count_of_member': {0: 40,
#                       1: 57615,
#                       2: 186000,
#                       4: 175000,
#                       5: 322458,
#                       6: 171000,
#                       7: 313758,
#                       8: 158000,
#                       10: 168000}}

# # Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Manage shop_id
shops = df['shop_id'].unique()

# set up plotly figure
fig = go.Figure()

# add one trace per NAR type and show counts per hospital
for shop in shops:

    # subset dataframe by shop_id
    df_ply=df[df['shop_id']==shop]

    # add trace
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_ply['AGE_GROUP'], y=df_ply['count_of_member'], name='shop_id'+str(shop)))

fig.show()
```

**EDIT:**

If you for some reason still need to structure your data as in your fourth sample, I suggest that you raise another question and specifically tag it with `[pandas]` and `[python]` ***only***, and exclusively focus on the data transformation part of the question.

Comment: sure, i will try that

Comment: @VincentYau Happy to help! I hope this is what you were looking for. And I hope you don't mind, but I'd just like to point out that you've recently gathered enough reputation points to earn the right to award posts with your up-votes. I assure you they will be highly appreciated. The forum even encourages the use of your votes through a couple of badges. Voting on 600 posts (and 25% or more of total votes are on questions) will even earn you a [gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)